# iText 2.1.7 and the ever-popular "page x of y" footer

Tags: java, itext

I am writing a back-end that generates PDF files; it works. We're using iText 2.1.7; it's been around in my shop a long time, so it's what's here.

I'm trying to generate "Page X of Y" in a footer without reading the entire document to get the number of pages. It almost works.

I have the following two methods in a class that implements PdfPageEventHelper:

```
    /**
     * at the end of each page, write out our footer, including the
     * 'totalPages' template.
     */
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) { 
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        cb.saveState();

//        cb.beginMarkedContentSequence(new PdfName("Artifact"));

        cb.setColorFill(MEDIUM_GRAY);

        String idString = String.format("ID : %s", proposalId);
        String pageString = String.format("Page %s of ", writer.getPageNumber());
        // dateString already formatted

        float textBase = document.bottom() - 20;
        float pageTextSize =  baseFont.getWidthPoint(pageString, footerTextSize);

        cb.beginText();
        cb.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 8);

        cb.setTextMatrix((document.right() / 8), textBase);
        cb.showText(idString);

        cb.setTextMatrix((document.right() / 2), textBase);
        cb.showText(pageString);

        cb.setTextMatrix(((document.right() / 8) * 7), textBase);
        cb.showText(dateString);

        cb.addTemplate(totalPages, (document.right() / 2) + pageTextSize, textBase);
        cb.endText();

//        cb.endMarkedContentSequence();

        cb.restoreState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        totalPages.beginText();
        totalPages.setFontAndSize(baseFont, footerTextSize);
        totalPages.setTextMatrix(0, 0);
        totalPages.showText(String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber() - 1));
        totalPages.endText();
    }
```

This does indeed put "Page 1 of 9", etc., through the document. However, intermittently, Acrobat reader tells its user that the document has a bad format. We have one machine and user that can make this error appear consistently, every time he opens such a document. If I remove just these two methods, that doesn't happen.

I saw a post elsewhere from Bruno Lowagie indicating that, since this text was not part of the main document, it needed to be "tagged", and giving an example of calling the methods 'beginMarkedContentSequence()' and 'endMarkedContentSequence()', shown above though commented out. The example I saw used the constant PdfName.ARTIFACT in the first call, but that constant is only available in a later version of iText. I looked up its source, and found that the constant is just created by instantiating a PdfName as shown, so I thought I'd try that. When I do that, however, iText throws an exception:

```
ERROR:[10:28:41] ProposalManagementController.saveProposal.PUBLISH:  Unknown Error trying to publish Proposal.
com.lowagie.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced begin/end marked content operators.
  at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.endMarkedContentSequence(Unknown Source)
  at com.accesspointinc.proposals.ProposalPDFGen$FooterWriter.onEndPage(ProposalPDFGen.java:1784)
  at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.newPage(Unknown Source)
  at com.lowagie.text.Document.newPage(Unknown Source)
  at com.accesspointinc.proposals.ProposalPDFGen.insertLocationSummaryTable(ProposalPDFGen.java:282)
  at com.accesspointinc.proposals.ProposalPDFGen.addPricing(ProposalPDFGen.java:219)
  at com.accesspointinc.proposals.ProposalPDFGen.generatePDF(ProposalPDFGen.java:104)
  at com.accesspointinc.proposals.ProposalManagementController.saveProposal(ProposalManagementController.java:410)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
```

So, is there a way to do this from iText 2.1.7?

Comment: **A** Whether or not it is due to missing tags, depends on the document in question. If it is not tagged to start with, headers and footers do not need to be tagged either. Thus, the PDF in question would have to be checked, before and after processing. **B** If there indeed is an issue in that old version and it works in current versions, that should be an incentive to update.

Comment: We have no tags in the document currently; are you saying that we should not therefore have any trouble with untagged content in the footer? I only thought it was the issue based on the fact that we got an error and Mr. Lowagie's post. If you have anything else to suggest that could be causing a problem in this code, I'd appreciate hearing about it. Yeah, there are various incentives to update, or just to change libraries

Comment: Have you checked whether the situation in that post from Bruno really matches your situation? Absent tags can only be a problem if tags are required, and that oftentimes is not the case. *If you have anything else to suggest* . supply sample PDFs (before and after going through your code) to analyze.

Comment: I'd be happy to provide a sample PDF that illustrates the error, but don't know how to do it here; It has non-printable chars, and there's no attachment provision at SO that I know of.

Comment: SO does not have such a provision. Usually people share such files e.g. via a public dropbox or googledrive share (no file sharer with many adds, please) and post the URL here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4YtVAkZfJrfc0h5WXdYUzAyYTg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100177/discussion-between-arcy-and-mkl).